# Display CSS: some divs fixed, some flexible

Tags: html, css, fixed

I need the following to happen in my website:
The counter and logo (top, bottom) should always have the same height and stay on the top and bottom even though the screen height will decrease/increase. BUT the 2 other divs in between should get smaller/bigger when the window changes. I hope with this example its easier to understand:

[image: pic]

The logo will disappear when the screen height is too low, right now. Here is the css:

The section is 80% width and aside 20%, but that doesnt really matter here...

```
#countdown{
padding: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 3em;
margin: 0.5em;}

#addProject{
margin: 0.5em;
padding: 0 1em;
height: 44%;
overflow-y: auto;}

#Nye{
margin: 0.5em;
padding: 0 1em;
overflow-y: auto;
height: 40%;
}

#logo{
margin: 1em;
height: 5em; 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code so people can have a look and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Rémi offered a good start, but I would recommend using position: fixed.

This will anchor your elements to the browser window, regardless of the amount of your content.

e.g.:

```
.counter, .middle1, .middle2, .logo {
    position: fixed;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 200px;
    right:0;
}
.counter {
    background: yellow;
    top:0;
    height: 50px;
}
.middle1 {
    overflow: scroll;
    background: blue;
    top:50px;
    bottom: 50%;
}
.middle2 {
    overflow: scroll;
    background: green;
    top: 50%;
    bottom:50px;
}
.logo {
    background: pink;
    bottom:0;
    height: 50px;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/uKPEn/1/

Comment: worked very well. but can I ask you another question, how can I have those divs a fixed width as well. I thought I can do it with min-width , but when I decrease the window-width they are becoming smaller instead of beeing fixed, not changing size.thx

Comment: As you probably found, fixed width is actually easier to accomplish. You had mentioned that the aside was 20% wide, so I was offering a solution to handle that while enforcing a minimum—I saw in your example that you had a few buttons in your aside. I'd recommend testing a touch in older browsers to be sure things are working right. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little tricky but I discovered by doing it that it is actually doable without javascript. Here is a fiddle to illustrate it http://jsfiddle.net/2LyUy/3/

You have to do 3 things:

- wrap your two middle divs in a new div, for example with id="wrap".
- put a different position attribute on your aside (for example "relative", which will actually not move your div at all)
- then have fixed size counter and logo

The css gives that (don't forget to wrap your 2 middle divs with a new one):

```
aside#test { position: relative; }
           /* so that the "absolute" below work as expected */
           /* any of "relative" "absolute" or "fixed" positioning would work here, depending on the needs */

#countdown {
    position: absolute; left:0; right:0; /* could be factored out if preferred */
    top:0; height: 150px;
}
#logo {
    position: absolute; left:0; right:0;
    bottom:0; height: 50px;
}
#wrap {
    position: absolute; left:0; right:0;
    top:150px; bottom: 50px;
}
#addProject {
    position: absolute; left:0; right:0;
    top:0; height:50%;
}
#Nye {
    position: absolute; left:0; right:0;
    bottom:0; height:50%;
}
```

Here is the div wrapping code extract:

```
            </div></div>
        <div id="wrap">  <!-- added -->
        <div id="addProject" 
    ....
<br>
</div>
            </div> <!-- added -->
            <div .... id="logo"></div>
```

Comment: NB: I wrote the css before you added yours so the ids/classes are not matching

Comment: hey thanks so far. it seems to work, but do I have to position the "section" also absolute? look in my example I have a big section and an aside

Comment: I think it is the simplest thing to do (positioning the section as absolute) in your case. See http://jsfiddle.net/2LyUy/4/

Comment: i didnt really work out with my page. i uploaded an example to http://wiesenberg.info/stack ! can you try to use your technique and adjust it to my page? i tried to do it like you, but it didnt work. that would be very very nice!

Comment: I could make it work on your page, I'll update my post with your IDs