# Display CSS: some divs fixed, some flexible (2)

Tags: html, css, fixed

somehow I am very bad at this so i need your help guys. The problem is similar to my previous problem (find it here: [Display CSS: some divs fixed, some flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893578/display-css-some-divs-fixed-some-flexible)).

This time I need #DIV-3 to be the flexible one that gets small and big as the window height changes and all other DIVS need to be fixed. So here is an illustration:
[image]

Can someone please help my with a fiddle like last time.
Thank you very much.

this is code example, but doesnt really matter probably:

```
#DIV-1{
position: fixed;
padding: 1em 2em;
top: 6.8em;
right: 0;
height: 9.5em;
width: 18%;
bottom: 75%;
}

#DIV-2{
position: fixed;
padding: 1em 2em;
width: 18%;
top: 16em;
bottom: 18em;
right: 0;
}

#DIV-3{
position: fixed;
padding: 1em 2em;
bottom: 0em;
right: 0;
width: 18%;
height: 18em;
overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: I actually have a hard time envisioning how this would look. A "fixed" element ignores scrolling entirely; it's like it's glued to your browser viewport. Do you just want it to be as tall as the page is (and I guess, not fixed?)

Comment: wheres your fiddle? or if you dont have one, attempt to implement what you think should happen so we can help you instead of just writing code for you

Comment: yeah not fixed then, I just want div1 and 2 to have a fixed height and div3 adjust to the height of the window and have a scrollbar when its too low

Comment: the fiddle is similar to my last question-post. except I dont need 2 middle divs to be flexible, but the last one and all others have a fixed height

Comment: Oh...we're supposed to use the fiddle of the accepted answer...so we're using the work someone else coded for you to code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you want (using the answer from your other question) ... horrible way to build something though haha.

http://jsfiddle.net/uKPEn/5/

```
.middle1 {
    background: blue;
    height: 100px;
    top:50px;
}
.middle2 {
    background: green;
    top: 150px;
    height: 100px;
}
.logo {
    background: pink;
    overflow: scroll;
    top: 250px;
    bottom:0%;
}
```

Not exactly sure, but you could consider using something like [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html) or [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) for building stuff that fits together like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS function `calc()`

```
html, body {
    background-color: transparent;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size:8pt;
}

#header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: auto;
    height: 6.8em;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#section {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% - 18%);
    height: calc(100% - 6.8em);
    overflow-x: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    float: left;
}

#DIV-1 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid purple;
    height: 9.5em;
    width: 18%;
}

#DIV-2 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 9.5em;
    width: 18%;
}

#DIV-3 {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    height: calc(100% - 25.8em);
    width: 18%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="header">Header</div>
<div id="section">Section</div>
<div id="DIV-1">1</div>
<div id="DIV-2">2</div>
<div id="DIV-3">3</div>
```

Example on: http://jsfiddle.net/7baotd4o/

`calc` allows us to, *surprise*, calculate a value for CSS.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc